# Need YTD and MTD calculations in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

```
Date       Amt  ytd mtd
01-Jan-21   1   2   2
01-Jan-21   1   2   2
02-Jan-21   1   3   3
03-Jan-21   1   4   4
01-Feb-21   1   5   1
02-Feb-21   1   6   2
03-Feb-21   1   7   3
04-Feb-21   1   8   4
05-Feb-21   1   9   5
01-Mar-21   1   10  1
02-Mar-21   1   11  2
03-Mar-21   1   12  3
04-Mar-21   1   13  4
01-Apr-21   1   14  1
02-Apr-21   1   15  2
03-Apr-21   1   16  3
01-May-21   1   17  1
02-May-21   1   18  2
03-May-21   1   19  3
04-May-21   1   20  4
05-May-21   1   21  5
06-May-21   1   22  6
```

I have the first two columns (Date, Amt) and i need the YTD and MTD columns in MS SQL so that i can show the above table.

Comment: If you are using `SQL Server`, why also tagged `MySQL` and `Postgresql` ?

Comment: Why is your first ytd and mtd 2 if the first Amt is 1?

Comment: You need to use `SUM () OVER ( PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)`. Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @crimson589 ... The date is same for both the rows. So for that date, i should show me data for that date

Comment: Why MTD for 01-Jan-21 is equal to 2, not 1? why MTD for 03-Apr-21 is 2, not 3?

Comment: @Akina typo error. #rd april is 3

Comment: Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a rolling COUNT OVER was used to calculate the ytd & mtd in the Oracle source.
*(Personally, I would prefere RANK or DENSE_RANK)*

And since Oracle datestamps can be casted to a DATE as-is.

> ```
> SELECT [Date], Amt
> , ytd = COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE)) 
> , mtd = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EOMONTH(CAST([Date] AS DATE)) ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE)) 
> FROM your_table
> ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE)
> ```

| Date | Amt | ytd | mtd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-21 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 01-Jan-21 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 02-Jan-21 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 03-Jan-21 | 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 01-Feb-21 | 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 02-Feb-21 | 1 | 6 | 2 |
| 03-Feb-21 | 1 | 7 | 3 |
| 04-Feb-21 | 1 | 8 | 4 |
| 05-Feb-21 | 1 | 9 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=72f18af356cc774f65dbe35d126a37ce)*

Comment: `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` would be wise, see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=495d370855ec81c76076aec2235844c6

Comment: @Charlieface But the OP's expected results also have 2 for 01-JAN-21, so it's fine without the ROWS.

Comment: Hum good point if that's what OP wants, about the only time I've ever seen that somebody *wanted* `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, it really is a stupid default. Do you see how strange those results look? Especially in a large dataset with only a few duplicates in the ordering key, suddenly your cumulative sum isn't actually cumulative.

Comment: @Charlieface That default only really bothers me for the LAST_VALUE function. It's basically useless with the default, so you'll always end up using FIRST_VALUE with descending order.